# How do i unzip files with 7z and do not replace files that have the same name but different hash?

Tags: linux, batch-file, compression, 7-zip

How can i tell 7z to extract all the files in the directory, tell it to do not replace files that have the same name but different hash? preferably tell it to extract the files and rename them to their hash?

for example lets say i extract two zip files, both have x.dll but with a different hash (different version). i want to keep both, but if its the same version (same hash), then only keep one. and preferably rename the extracted file to its hash, how to do it?

Right now I am extracting this way :

```
 7z -y -aot -p"pass"  x "*.*"
```

(not all the files contain password, but if they do, its the same, so correct me if I am doing it wrong)

**To give context,** i have a large number of installer files (.msi or .exe files that contain a lot of exes inside them), and i need to extract all the unique executables inside of them

Right now i am using the linux version of 7z, but i can use the Windows version too (inside a VM)

Comment: I suspect you're probably not going to be able to do this in one pass, because generally you can't compute the hash without decompressing all the data, so this would require a two-pass implementation, which probably isn't implemented.

Comment: Are you interested in two-pass implementation?

Comment: @ItWasn'tMe yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this is my `\Test Folder\*.*`:

```
I:\> tree /f /a
Folder PATH listing for volume 2ndHD
Volume serial number is FACF-B9ED
I:.
\---Test Folder
        extract n file 001.exe
        extract n file 002.msi
        extract y file 001.msi
        extract y file 002.exe
        extract y file 003.exe
        extract y file 003.msi
        file non exe msi.dat
        file non exe msi.log
```

These are the CRCs of my files [`.exe | .msi`] present in my `Folder Test\*.*`

```
I:\> @echo\File CRC:     File Size:  File Names exe^|msi & @"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" h "I:\Test Folder\*.*"|%__AppDir__%FindSTR.exe /ei "\.exe \.msi"
 7z CRC:     Size .7z:  file .7z name exe|msi:
4F993E11         19320  extract n file 001.exe
93922786           230  extract n file 002.msi
754077D4          2018  extract y file 001.msi
324BD0AB          2112  extract y file 002.exe
CA78246F          2098  extract y file 003.exe
26176047          9164  extract y file 003.msi
```

- **Obs.:** For the Output of the **`7z h`** command used, and filtered by `Findstr`, the size is disposable, but in getting the CRC and name, we can use in another loop to find that CRC and extract the relevant file when another one matches with an item in the `Test Folder`.

```
variable      ==> %%~i
tokens^=1     ==> 754077D4

variable                      ==> %%~j
tokens^= 2                    ==> 2018

variable                                  ==> %%~k
tokens^=  *                               ==> extract y file 001.msi

tokens^=1-2*  ==> 754077D4          2018      extract y file 001.msi
```

These are the results of listing my 7z file and filtering so that I get the CRC strings in the output by `FindSTR`:

```
I:\> "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" l -slt "H:\Q1634964.7z" -p"123456"|%__AppDir__%FindSTR.exe /bi "CRC.=...*"
CRC = B3871A85
CRC = 754077D4
CRC = 26176047
CRC = 7499157E
CRC = CA78246F
CRC = 324BD0AB
```

Using a `For /F` loop, I can get the CRC strings from each `".exe | .msi"` file present in file inside the **`.7z`**, and use another `For /F` to find the string CRC in oputput, that match in a local file\loop in my **`\Folder Test\`**:

```
for /f useback^tokens^=1-2* %%i in (`"7z.exe h "I:\Test Folder\*.*"|FindSTR /ei "\.exe \.msi"" 
`)do for /f useback^tokens^=2delims^=^= %%I in (`"7z.exe l -slt "H:\Q1634964.7z" -p"123456"|FindSTR /bi "CRC"|FindSTR.exe /c:"%%~i""
```

Using a `For /F` loop, I can get the CRC [`%%~i`] strings from the files present in **`H: \Q1634964.7z`**, and with an additional **`For /F`** loop that uses the CRC obtained in the first loop, to get CRC and the names[`%%~k`] of the files when this occurred, you can easily extract file where the CRC matches and everything together would be...

- In your command line:

```
@pushd %__AppDir__% && @(for /f useback^tokens^=1-2* %i in (`""C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" h "I:\Test Folder\*.*"|@FindSTR.exe /ei "\.exe \.msi""`)do @for /f useback^tokens^=2delims^=^= %I in (`""C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" l -slt "H:\Q1634964.7z" -p"123456"|FindSTR.exe /bi "CRC"|FindSTR.exe /c:"%~i""`)do @set/p "'= 7z CRC: %~i | File CRC: %~I | Results: %~k | Status: "<nul & "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" e "H:\Q1634964.7z" -y o "%temp%\%~k" -r -p"123456"|Findstr.exe "Ok ERROR") & @popd
```

- In Your bat file:

```
@echo off 

pushd %__AppDir__% 
Setlocal EnabledelayeDexpansion
set "_7z=C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" 

for /f useback^tokens^=1-2* %%i in (`""!_7z!" h "I:\Test Folder\*.*"|@FindSTR.exe /ei "\.exe \.msi""
     `)do for /f useback^tokens^=2delims^=^= %%I in (`""!_7z!" l -slt "H:\Q1634964.7z" -p"123456"|FindSTR.exe /bi "CRC"|FindSTR.exe /c:"%%~i""
     `)do set/p "'= 7z CRC: %%~i | File CRC: %%~I | Results: %%~k | Status: "<nul & "!_7z!" e "H:\Q1634964.7z" -y o "%temp%\%%~k" -r -p"123456"|Findstr.exe "Ok ERROR"
     
popd & endlocal & goto :eOf
```

- Results:

```
7z CRC: 754077D4 | File CRC:  754077D4 | Results: extract y file 001.msi | Status: Everything is Ok
7z CRC: 324BD0AB | File CRC:  324BD0AB | Results: extract y file 002.exe | Status: Everything is Ok
7z CRC: CA78246F | File CRC:  CA78246F | Results: extract y file 003.exe | Status: Everything is Ok
7z CRC: 26176047 | File CRC:  26176047 | Results: extract y file 003.msi | Status: Everything is Ok
```

---

If you don't need additional status outputs:

- In your command line:

```
@pushd %__AppDir__% && @(for /f useback^tokens^=1-2* %i in (`""C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" h "I:\Test Folder\*.*"|@FindSTR.exe /ei "\.exe \.msi""`)do @for /f useback^tokens^=2delims^=^= %I in (`""C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" l -slt "H:\Q1634964.7z" -p"123456"|FindSTR.exe /bi "CRC"|FindSTR.exe /c:"%~i""`)do @"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" e "H:\Q1634964.7z" -y o "%temp%\%~k" -r -p"123456") & @popd
```

- In your batch file:

```
@echo off 

pushd %__AppDir__% 
Setlocal EnabledelayeDexpansion
set "_7z=C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" 

for /f useback^tokens^=1-2* %%i in (`""!_7z!" h "I:\Test Folder\*.*"|@FindSTR.exe /ei "\.exe \.msi""`)do for /f useback^tokens^=2delims^=^= %%I in (`
""!_7z!" l -slt "H:\Q1634964.7z" -p"123456"|FindSTR.exe /bi "CRC"|FindSTR.exe /c:"%%~i""`)do "!_7z!" e "H:\Q1634964.7z" -y o "%temp%\%%~k" -r -p"123456"|Findstr.exe "Ok ERROR"
     
popd & endlocal & goto :eOf
```

---

To rename your files, where I assume you want/need is  hash (`"%%~i %%~k"`) resulting in the `"Hash Name.eXtension"` ==> **`"CA78246F extract y file 002.exe"`**

- In your command line:

```
@pushd %__AppDir__% && @(for /f useback^tokens^=1-2* %i in (`"@"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" h "I:\Test Folder\*.*"|@FindSTR.exe /ei "\.exe \.msi""`)do @for /f useback^tokens^=2delims^=^= %I in (`"@"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" l -slt "H:\Q1634964.7z" -p"123456"|@FindSTR.exe /bi "CRC"|FindSTR.exe /c:"%~i""`)do @"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" x "H:\Q1634964.7z" -y -o"%temp%" "%~k" -r -p"123456"|@Findstr.exe /e "Ok" >nul && <con: @rename "%temp%\%~k" "%~i %~k") & @popd
```

- In your bat/cmd file:

```
@echo off 

pushd %__AppDir__%
Setlocal EnabledelayeDexpansion
set "_7z=C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" 

for /f useback^tokens^=1-2* %%i in (`""!_7z!" h "I:\Test Folder\*.*"|FindSTR.exe /ei "\.exe \.msi""
    `)do for /f useback^tokens^=2delims^=^= %%I in (`""!_7z!" l -slt "H:\Q1634964.7z" -p"123456"|FindSTR.exe /bi "CRC"|FindSTR.exe /c:"%%~i""
        `)do "!_7z!" x "H:\Q1634964.7z" -y -o"%temp%" "%%~k" -r -p"123456"|Findstr.exe /e "Ok" >nul && <con: rename "%temp%\%%~k" "%%~i %%~k"

<con: popd & endlocal & goto :eOf
```

---

#### Additional Resources **[7-zip](/questions/tagged/7-zip)**:

- [7-Zip Online Help](https://7ziphelp.com/)
- [7-Zip Command-line Help](https://7ziphelp.com/7zip-command-line)
- [7-Zip Command-Line Examples](https://thedeveloperblog.com/7-zip-examples)
- [Zip Command Line Version User's Guide](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/)

#### Additional Resources **[cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)/[bat](/questions/tagged/bat)**:

- [`Dir /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html)
- [`For /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)
- [`For /F`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/for)
- [`Tree /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/tree.html)
- [`Findstr`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/findstr)
- [`Pushd /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/pushd.html)

  - [`Popd /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/popd.html)
- [Redirection](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)

  - `|`, `<`, `>`, `2>`, etc.
- Undocumented variables :

  - [`%__AppDir__%`](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6137)  | [`%__CD__%`](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6137)
  - [Environment](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html)
- [How does the Windows Command Interpreter [`cmd.exe`] Parse Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4094699/6819406)